# jqxDropDownList Listing is seperately opened at bottom of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If I include all the lib jqwidgets/jqx-all.js
it works well, but if I use only the necessary files given in their example : https://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxdropdownlist/index.htm#demos/jqxdropdownlist/defaultfunctionality.htm

then the listing appears at the end of the html file and not just under the widget.
I tried to include all the necessary files, didn't succeed.

Any idea?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jqwidgets/styles/jqx.base.css" type="text/css" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1 maximum-scale=1 minimum-scale=1" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jqwidgets/jqxcore.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jqwidgets/jqxbuttons.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jqwidgets/jqxscrollbar.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jqwidgets/jqxlistbox.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jqwidgets/jqxdropdownlist.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id='content'>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var source = [
                "Affogato",
                "Americano",
                "Bicerin",
                "Breve",
                "Café Bombón",
                "Café au lait"
            ];
            // Create a jqxDropDownList
            $("#jqxWidget").jqxDropDownList({ source: source, placeHolder: "Select Item", width: 250, height: 30});
        });
    </script>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <div id='jqxWidget'>
    </div>
    <hr>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem

it was the old version that I used : jqwidgets-ver8.0.0.zip

jqwidgets-ver8.3.2.zip  solved the issue

So always update to latest version...